# How to implement projects in Backbone.js TODOS-app?

Tags: model-view-controller, javascript, backbone.js

Hey! I'm trying out Backbone.js and have followed the [annotated source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html) of the [TODO's app](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html).

I fail (don't know how this should be done) when trying to implement projects, which has tasks as "children". So that i can change project and view different lists of tasks.

How should i do this? Some tips for beginner tutorials would also be great :)

Comment: How do you fail? What kind of errors are you seeing?

Comment: I don't fail that way. I don't really know how i should implement this the best way? Another model & collection with projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backbone docs mention a pattern for doing something like this:

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-nested

So, I would create a new model called a project that has a property called 'tasks' which is an instance of a TodoList collection.

I can't speak to storing the data, as I've never looked at the localStorage used in the TODO app.